# A Remote Location

Tags: knowledge, story, no-computers, chess, history

Here be a simple problem

For the keen directmate eye

White to move and win

In seven moves, Black shall die

---

[image]

---

However, I remember now a relative

Long ago did he begin to live

About a two decades or so

After the mid-nineteenth you know

---

We have the same theme, that’s to say

Can you give me relative’s father’s name?

Can you you also say our theme?

It’s chess problem related, quite a beautiful scheme

---

Give me the correct solution and the father’s name

And you’ll some points for playing this game!

It will help to solve first, that’s my call

Have great fun and good luck to all

Hint:

> For the theme, refer to the title!

Comment: Is the chess puzzle original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer (solution to the chess problem, fixed by @Remellion):

> **1. Kd1-c1!** (imprisoning the black king) **1... b7-b6** (1... g7xh6 2. h7-h8=Q(B) mate) **2. h7-h8=N!** (the knight is the only piece which can mate, since a queen/bishop promotion stalemates Black, and the rook is useless, because both the 1st rank and the a-file are blocked) **2...g7xh6** (shorter is 2... g7-g5 (or similarly 2...g7-g6) 3. Nh8-f7(g6) g5-g4 4. h6-h7 g4-g3 5. h7-h8=Q(B) mate) **3. Nh8-g6 h6-h5 4. Ng6-f4 h5-h4 5. Nf4xd3 h4-h3 6. Nd3-e1 h3-h2 7. Ne1-c2 mate**

P.S. Maybe it's related to

> knighting ceremony (since the main theme is (under)promotion to a knight)?

P.P.S. Or is it related to

> Vladimir Lenin? (since he was born in 1870, exactly 20 years after the middle of 19th century, and was widely known by his patronymic name *Ilyich*, meaning that his father is named Ilya (i.e. Elias). The theme is probably related to the Russian Great October Socialist Revolution of 1917, either to imprisoning the former monarch, Nicolas II (like the black king in chess problem), or the famous 1st Cavalry Army (knight promotion)).

Comment: Chess solution is wrong. Black pawn will be on b6 guarding a5. Try going to d3 then c2 instead.